# Extract all a `href`s from webpage with htmlagilitypack/requests anything

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I have this web page source:

```
<a href="/StefaniStoikova"><img alt="" class="head" id="face_6306494" src="http://img0.ask.fm/assets/054/771/271/thumb_tiny/sam_7082.jpg" /></a>
<a href="/devos"><img alt="" class="head" id="face_18603180" src="http://img7.ask.fm/assets/043/424/871/thumb_tiny/devos.jpg" /></a>
<a href="/frenop"><img alt="" class="head" id="face_4953081" src="http://img1.ask.fm/assets/029/163/760/thumb_tiny/dsci0744.jpg" /></a>
```

And I want to extract the string right after the `<a href-"`. But my main problem is that these strings are different and I don't seem to find a way. With neither agilitypack or webrequests.

Maybe someone has idea about regular expression? Share it.

Comment: You want to extract the `href` property or whole line? It is easy to do with jquery if you want to it on client-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be quite simple to get what you need with the HtmlAgilityPack. Assuming you have your document loaded into an `HtmlDocument` object named `doc`:

```
HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

foreach (HtmlNode node in collection)
{
    // Do what you want with the href value in here. As an example, this just
    //  just prints the value to the console.
    Console.WriteLine(node.GetAttributeValue("href", "default"));
}
```